# How do you join on floating point columns in SQL?

Tags: sql

Is it legal in ANSI SQL (or important implementations) to join on floating point columns?

I'm sure that it is generally not a good idea, but I'm working on an API and looking to SQL for guidance as to whether it should be prevented, or left to the developer to choose.

If it is legal, do you have the option to specify a precision to use in the comparison?

Comment: Underlying problem: does it make sense for a floating point value to be part of a (primary, natural, candidate, foreign, ...) *KEY* ? Answer: probably only as part of a {min,max} range. (the floating-point representation of date[time] values in SAS (and in Postgres <= pg8.3) can be painfull) Next question: how often do you need to join on non-Key fields?

Comment: It is valid and can work, but rounding can cause unexpected records if not anticipated. You shouldn't prevent a developer from doing things the language is capable of doing.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Remember, juggling chainsaws is *legal*.

Comment: I see this in data that has been migrated from another DBMS. If you can change the way the data type maps, this would be the best solution. If not I've had some success with changing the joins to look like "ON str(FloatField) = str(OtherFloatField)". This is less efficient since its got to convert all the values from both fields before comparing.

Answer (score 5):

SQL allows joining on any columns and any conditions.

However, you should not allow joining on floating point columns, if you can prevent using equality conditions on such columns.  The simple replacement is to allow joins on *decimal*/*numeric* columns.

What is the problem?  WYSIWIG (what-you-see-is-what-you-get) is the problem.  Two floating point values can look the same, and yet be different.  This causes `join`s to fail.

You can specify the conditions as essentially:

```
on abs(a - b) < 0.00001 -- your favorite threshold
```

but this prevents the use of an index.  Some databases may have "fuzzy" match for floating point numbers.

There are cases where you might want *inequality* joins using floating point values.  This would be when doing ranges:

```
limit       val
1.4142     'a'
2.7182     'b'
3.1415     'c'
```

But this is a rare condition -- particularly when the limits should be floating point rather than counts or monetary limits.